# Making a phone call in an iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, phone-call

I have some code which attempts to make a call within an application, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *theCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",phone];
    NSLog(@"making call with %@",theCall);
    [myApp openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theCall]];
```

Sometimes, the variable `phone` is something such as `@"(102) 222-2222"`. How can I make a call with a phone number like this? Do I need to manually extract the numbers out of it and get rid of all the extra punctuation?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yup. You need to take those out yourself. Or you can use the snippet below...

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", cleanedString]];
```

Note: you may be tempted to use `-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`, but that one only removes characters at the start and the end of the string, not if they appear in the middle.

Comment: According to the docs I don't think you need the // in the url. [Apple's phone URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1)

Comment: You are right marcfrodi. Indeed not needed, though iOS won't trip over them either. Anyway, answer has been updated.

Comment: is there a way to get callbacks if call fail due to low balance or network signal problem

Comment: @JohanKool Why not just use -`stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:` instead for removing the hypens?

Comment: @EvanR My snippet doesn't actually remove any hyphens, because that's not what causes the URL to fail to open. It removes any disallowed characters. Surely there is a way to implement similar code using `-stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:`, but I doubt it'll be as concise as this.

Comment: @JohanKool Ah, you're right--sorry, didn't look at the OP's question closely enough!

Answer (score 23):

To go back to original app you can use telprompt:// instead of tel:// - The tell prompt will prompt the user first, but when the call is finished it will go back to your app:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

just an update on above answer.

Comment: You are right but beware that the telprompt is not an official url scheme. Apple can remove this scheme in future version of iOS.

Comment: Then how to come back to the app if we don't use telprompt.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple method that can be used to make a call and return to the app after the call is finished.

Add the following to your .m file

```
- (void) dialNumber:(NSString*) number{
number = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:number];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:number]];
}
```

Then add the following code wherever you want to make the call from:

```
[self dialNumber:@"5031234567"];
```