# How to apply regex and/or clean a telephone string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a NSString that contains fax telephone numbers. Sometimes I get different formats entered for example: (877) xxx-xxxx or 877-xxx-xxxx.

How do I get about cleaning the NSSString so that all I get is XXXxxxxxx.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a phone call in an iOS application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323171/making-a-phone-call-in-an-ios-application)

Comment: @PengOne while this question and the one you linked are related it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`NSCharacterSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCharacterSet) and [`NSMutableCharacterSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can solve this problem in two ways.

1. If you already know the characters that you want to remove.

   ```
   NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-(),. "];
   NSArray *arrayWithNumbers = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet];
   NSString *numberStr = [arrayWithNumbers componentsJoinedByString:@""];
   ```
2. If you don't know the characters, you can use the different character sets available already

   ```
   NSMutableCharacterSet *charSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet new];
   [charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
   [charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];
   [charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
   NSArray *arrayWithNumbers = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet];
   NSString *numberStr = [arrayWithNumbers componentsJoinedByString:@""];
   ```