# iOS: phone number dialing not working

Tags: ios

I'm building an app that lets you call different service centers from Netherlands. The problem is that some of them have a different commercial format (like 0800-xxxx) and the device can't make the call.
The code looks like this:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
}
```

Do you have any idea how to format the number or to make the phone call, no matter it's format?

EDIT: This is how the phoneNumber is created:

```
NSString *phoneNumberString = phoneNumber; // dynamically assigned
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", phoneNumberString];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];
```

Comment: can you show the value of phoneURL? Is it in this format: `@"tel:9190432097420"`?

Comment: The format is like this:  
NSString *phoneNumberString = phoneNumber;    
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", phoneNumberString];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];

Comment: It works fine for a normal, valid phoneNumber format. But for a commercial one it doesn't.

Comment: any difference if you specify 'tel' instead of 'telprompt'?

Comment: Illegal characters in the number? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323171/making-a-phone-call-in-an-ios-application

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I used this code and it worked:

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *escapedPhoneNumber = [cleanedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", escapedPhoneNumber];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
}
```

Comment: What does the cleanedString accomplish? I am not convinced that it is necessary.

Comment: @NickSnyder I think it gets rid of spaces and other special characters. That way you just have a number which can then be called... I think.....

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *strm = (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)mob, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
NSString *strMob = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"tel://%@",strm];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strMob]];
```

try this code . This works perfectly for any kind of format.It will convert into perfect calling URL .

Comment: In this "mob" is for your mobile num which is in NSString format.

Comment: I used this code and it worked:
    NSString *cleanedString = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSString *escapedPhoneNumber = [cleanedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", escapedPhoneNumber];
    NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];

Comment: @AndraTodorescu, if you answer your own question, please place the answer in the answer section.  Not in a comment.