# How to initiate phone call by contact name on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, phone-call, forward

I know how to add a contact, I know how to initiate a phone call.
What I don't know, if it's possible to initiate a phone call only by contact name.
What I mean: I add a new contact with phone number with pin code, like 123456*9, this is possible as I already did it.

Answer (score 0):

How call can be initiated when you don't add contact number in this?
BTW I found in Apple docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1)

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number. If your application receives URL strings from the user or an unknown source, you should also make sure that any special characters that might not be appropriate in a URL are escaped properly. For native applications, use the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method of NSString to escape characters, which returns a properly escaped version of your original string.

and please check if this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323171/making-a-phone-call-in-an-ios-application) works for you.

Comment: As I said, I add a number to the contact, but the number is with pin code, like 123456*9. But I cannot make phone call with '*' or '#'.

Comment: Can you show me an example on this with screenshot to get it fully

Comment: There is nothing to show. (1) Add contact with pin code - no problem (2) Pick this contact and phone call it - have no idea

Comment: @seza- But in this solution the URL is taken right without having special character within it

Comment: @idan Moshe- Tell me if it is helpful for you?